# Save OpenCV image into external server path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I use `cv2.imwrite()` to save my picture in server.
While i try to save it in local disk, no issue, all below code runs correctly. However, when i try to save it in our server, it is not been saved. I run it on Windows 10.
My code:

```
path = "\\\\myServer\\myPath\\"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
path = path + "croppedImage.jpg"
croppedImg = getCropedImg(img, ROI) # this method is tested, no problem
cv2.imwrite(path, croppedImg)
```

there is no problem with myPath. I checked the path and it has exist.
When I try above code for local disk, It works corectly.

Comment: I think problem with Windows server was already few times on Stackoverflow - and it is problem with file systems in Python, not directly in `CV2`

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas cv2.imwirite doesn't have any Errror message

Comment: @furas I didn't look as file system scope, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about opencv and python path issue. Files are not been able to written or read from server path using `opencv`. I solved it firstly saving in local and copying it via `shutil.copy2`

```
def writeImage(path, img):
        """ Write image to given path"""
        tmpPath = "img.png"
        cv.imwrite(tmpPath, img)
        copy2(tmpPath, path)
        os.remove("img.png")
```